# How to access variables from the main method in another class

Tags: java, methods, static, public

This is probably a noob question but oh well, I need to collect the frameWidth and frameHeight variables from my main method

---

frame.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    .....
    .......                                                
    int frameWidth  = frame.getContentPane().getWidth();
    int frameHeight  = frame.getContentPane().getHeight();
}
```

Board.java

```
public class board extends JPanel {
    private frame Frame;

    public board() {
        Frame = new frame();
        int FrameWidth = frame.main().frameWidth;
        int FrameWidth = frame.main().frameHeight;
    }
}
```

---

What is the proper way of accessing the variable?

Comment: .. and `Board` not `board`

Comment: Java methods do not have properties.   You can not access **local** variables outside a method they're defined in.

Comment: ... and don't mix Swing (JPanel) and AWT (Frame) components needlessly. Stick with Just Swing (JFrame).

Answer (score 2):

Pass it into the constructor:

```
private int width = 0, height= 0;
public Board(int width, int height){
  ...
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}
```

Then in your `main`:

```
Board myBoard = new Board(FrameWidth, FrameHeight);
```

Your class will now have access to the variables `FrameWidth` and `FrameHeight` as `width` and `height`, respectively.

Comment: Hi Astro this doesnt answer the OP's situation, he needs to get the height and width from the Main class, not set it from there. The frame could be resized.

Comment: @boolean This doesn't set it; it allows him to access the values of `frameWidth` and `frameHeight` "**from** the main method **in another** class" as the variables `width` and `height` for use **in** that class.

Comment: I don't think I am able to send the height and width through the parameters because the the jframe hasn't been set visible yet....

Comment: Construct the Board after they're set to visible.

Comment: @AstroCB But I have the line `frame.getContentPane().add(new board());` and I'm not sure if that's possible

Comment: Fair enough; as far as I know, that's the only way to do it, so if you can't access the value there, you'll have to restructure your code or take a look at some of the options below (some of which I believe misinterpret your question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the board (the class should be capital B) object in the Main class and define getters for width and height like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
Board board = new Board();                                              
int frameWidth  = board.getWidth();
int frameHeight  = board.getHeight();
}

public class board extends JPanel {
private frame Frame;

public board() {
    Frame = new frame();
    int FrameWidth = frame.frameWidth;
    int FrameWidth = frame.frameHeight;
}
public int getWidth(){
     return frame.frameWidth;
}

public int getHeight(){
    return frame.frameHeight;

}
}
```

Comment: The method main(String[]) in the type frame is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: @unableToCompile sorry I cpy pasted your code, remove the main() call from frame. I assume some frame customized class.

Comment: I don't think you read my question correctly, I have a main method that has the values of the frame width and length. NOW, I need to grab those variables from my board class in board.java